# Asp.net js/css grouping at compile time

Tags: asp.net, performance

I want to create a group of all js files added in given aspx page and save in some folder with the guid(formed by the hash of all content) as the file name and content as the combined & crunched content of all js files.

Currently I am doing at runtime but there is some performance hit during first time and also performance hit when I am using httpHandler to serve this file. I need to use httpHander at run time because we are using multiple web server and the grouped file may not be present in other webserver. At present along with writing the file on disk we are also storing in db (common place), so that it will be accessible from other webserver..

Because of performance reason we want to do at compile time.
Meaning, at compile time I want to know which all scripts are going to be added at runtime and I will create that combined js on disk and replace all those tags with just one static tag. So, that it will severed efficiently by IIS. Pls suggest how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.